# admob Smartbanner ad always returns NoFill error in both emulator/device Windows

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob, unity-container, windows-phone-8-emulator

**Admob Ad integration in Windows phone 8.0**
Admob SDK version : 6.5.13
visual studio 2015 IDE : 4.6.00079

Test 1 :
Ad formart : Banner Ad
forceTesting = true;
Result : Works.

Test 2 :
Ad formart : Banner Ad
forceTesting = false;
Result : Works.

Test 3 :
Ad formart : smartBanner Ad
forceTesting = true;
Result : Works.

Test 4 :
Ad formart : smartBanner Ad
forceTesting = false;
Result : No Fill error - Always.

Am using Sample provided by Admob from their website.
**GoogleAds.ExampleApps.BannerExampleCode :**
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-wp8-examples/tree/master/examples/GoogleAds.ExampleApps.BannerExampleCode

```
   private void CreateAd()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(" CreateAd ");

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // NOTE: Edit "MY_AD_UNIT_ID" with your ad unit id.
            bannerAd = new AdView
            {
                Format = AdFormats.Banner,
                AdUnitID = "AdUnit ID here"
            };
            bannerAd.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
            bannerAd.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
            bannerAd.FailedToReceiveAd += OnFailedToReceiveAd;
            DrawingSurfaceBackground.Children.Add(bannerAd);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
            adRequest.ForceTesting = false;
            bannerAd.LoadAd(adRequest);

        });

    }
```

Do we have control over "NoFill rate error", Please help me.

Comment: Please post your code as part of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly to SO.

Comment: how to post your code as part of a MCVE directly to SO ?. What is So ? please explain.